# Getting postid from permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I get post id from the url. For instance I have opened the page `mysiteurl/mypagename`
in the page handler i need to get post id.

If I had default permalinks than I could get from the name **/?p=123** but I have non-default ones so I cannot get post ID from the name

Something like UNPERMALINK because it does the reverse as the_permalink.

NB - I dont have the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the wordpress framework loaded you can use [url_to_postid()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) - the opposite of `get_permalink()`:

```
<?php $postid = url_to_postid( $url ); ?>
```

with your permalink as `$url`

Comment: Cool that;s what I need. But is there good n pretty way to get current url in wordress or php generally?

Comment: <?php $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>

Comment: Feel free to accept this as your answer with the checkbox if it works for you :)